# Zeroes of $1-n^{1-s}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $n$ be a positive integer. What are the zeroes of $1-n^{1-s}$ for $s\in\mathbb{C}$? I took it for granted that if $n^{1-s}=1$ then $1-s=0$, so $s=1$ but I think I'm missing some complex solutions.

Comment: Write $n^{1-s}$ as $e^{(1-s)\log(n)}$, now decompose $s$ in real and complex part $s=a+bi$ and see for which values this gives back something of the form $e^{2i\pi k},k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$
n^{1-s}=e^{2\pi ik}
$$
Taking logarithms, we get
$$
s=1-\frac{2\pi ik}{\log(n)}
$$
The case $s=1$ comes from $k=0$.